# find index meeting conditions across two matrices

Tags: r

Suppose I have 2 matrices

```
A <-matrix(runif(100), ncol=10) 
B <-matrix(runif(100), ncol=10)
```

How do I find all the index (i,j) such that A[i,j] < r1 and B[i,j] > r2 and store them in matrix C such that C[i,j] =1 and 0 otherwise. Here r1, r2 are two numbers between 0 and 1.  Do I have to convert A and B to data frames to boost efficiency?

A and B are very large in my original problem and therefore efficiency is the # 1 priority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think basic matrix math might be even quicker (actually for n=10e6 its aboout 6x)

```
set.seed(10)
A <-matrix(runif(1000000), ncol=1000) 
B <-matrix(runif(1000000), ncol=1000)

r1<-0.5
r2<-0.3

C<-(A > r1) * (B < r2)
```

TIMING

```
# timing 
A <-matrix(runif(1000000), ncol=1000) 
B <-matrix(runif(1000000), ncol=1000)



>     system.time({C <- A < r1 & B > r2
                   +     C[] <- as.numeric(C)
                   +     })
user  system elapsed 
0.06    0.00    0.06 
>     
  >     system.time(C<-(A > r1) * (B < r2))
user  system elapsed 
0.02    0.00    0.01
```

Comment: A tiny difference in absolute terms for a single trial, though it might be worth it if you are simulating thousands of repeats I suppose.

Comment: yup depends what "very large" means, but the point is it's more efficient (computation, memory and coding) to multiply 2 boolean matrices. e.g. for n=10e8, `C[] <- as.numeric(C)` will run out of (4GB) memory, but `C<-(A > r1) * (B < r2)` will  not

Comment: Fair enough point. I could hack around that issue by adding `+ 0` to the end of the comparison code, but the multiplication would probably be simpler still.

Answer (score 1):

`matrix` operations are probably quicker than converting to `data.frame`s

```
r1 <- 0.3
r2 <- 0.7
C <- A < r1 & B > r2
C[] <- as.numeric(C)
C

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     1
# [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0     0
# [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0
# [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     0
# [5,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0     1
# [6,]    1    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1     0
# [7,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0     0
# [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
# [9,]    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    1    0     0
#[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

Comment: maybe like the following?